# Pass url params from flask to angular

Tags: python, html, angularjs, flask

I have a flask route `search` that serves json search results and an `index` one that serves a page to search from, simplified as

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    res = querydb(request.args)
    return jsonify(res)


@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

In index.html, I have search forms linked to angular variables, and a button that queries `/search` using angular's `$http` and url params from the search forms.

I would like the ability to additionally fetch initial results based on the url (for example, let the url `/index?color=red` load the `/index` page and fetch results from `/search?color=red` on load).

To do this, I'm redefinig the jinja template tags as `<%blah%>` (to not interfere with angular's), and rendering the page with `render_template('index.html', color='red')`, with a snippet in the html like

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="fetch('<%color%>')"> </div>
```

There mustbe a better way to send the params from flask to angular (trying `$routeParams` or `$location.search()` doesn't seem to work with flask, returning empty objects). Or should I be composing the views differently somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle your page routes from angular and your API endpoints from flask. So your flask file might look like:

```
@app.route('/api/search')
def search():
    res = querydb(request.args)
    return jsonify(res)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**Angular App**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/index', {
                templateUrl: 'mainView.html'
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            });
});
```

**controller**

```
var MainCtrl = function($location, $http, $scope) {
    //Now you can access the search params
    var searchParams = $location.search();

    $http.get('/api/search?color=' + searchParams.color).success(function(data) {
        $scope.results = data;
    });
}
```

Now if you go to `http://somedomain/#/index?color=red` it should fetch the initial results. Note that Angular handels the part of the url after the `/#`. Also you'll need to include the `angular-route.js` file to get routing working in angular.

When you're using angular routing your `index.html` file will just have all the boiler plate stuff that you want to include in each view and the layout for your page will go into `mainView.html`. `index.html` will need to have `<div ng-view></div>` somewhere in the body to tell angular where to inject `mainView.html`

Comment: Thanks! If I'm reading correctly, 1) configuring the angular app with the `$routeProvider` is necessary to successfully use the `$location.search()`, and 2) `ng-view` is the replacement for `ng-include` while using angular's routing mechanism?

Comment: @BirdJaguarIV yes exactly. Although I guess you could probably get `location.search()` working without ngRoute if you manually put the `#/` into the url. I came across someone asking a similar question on GitHub that you might want to take a look at: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4607